# Git does not track the .gitignore exception folder

Tags: git, phpstorm, gitignore

At the root of the project is `.gitignore` and the `vendor` folder. The *gitignore* file contains:

`!vendor/folder` - except the folder in the vendor.

`vendor/` - exclude the entire vendor,

Git does not track changes to files in the `vendor` except one - `folder`. Everything is as it should be.

**Problem**: Git does not see the new files when I create them, just noticed.

I'm using PhpStorm and it usually suggests adding a new file to the git, but not for new files in the `folder`, similarly the console does not see new files.

The question is solved directly by the `gid add` command with the `-f` option, and warns in advance that the file is in a `folder` that is excluded (!) By one of the ignore files.

How to fix the situation and what's the problem?

Comment: You should not only un-ignore the folter, but the files as well (with the asterisks).

Comment: in the `vendor` folder there are a lot of other folders, should I list them all?

Comment: @ruleb: no, add `!vendor/folder/` and `!vendor/folder/*`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem didn't work

Answer (score 0):

I moved the exception below the `vendor` folder and changed the `vendor` -> `vendor/*`.

Now in `.gitignore`:

```
vendor/*

!vendor/lynx/
```